# Is there any Git web interfaces for locally hosted git projects?

Tags: git

I have a home server which I host all of my Git projects on and I would like to navigate commits and such like GitHub. Are there any web interfaces out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [git instaweb](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-instaweb.html) for your own instant gitweb instance. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on msysgit.

For a permanent installation, drop [gitweb.cgi](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) onto a webserver. Alternatives include [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/) (my preference, extremely fast), [gitalist](http://www.gitalist.com/). For a complete list, see the [git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#Web_Interfaces), but the ones I listed are the ones you would want to try.

Answer (score 1):

you can get [github firewall install](http://fi.github.com/) to host your git repos. Or you could use [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/)

Comment: Gitorious is nearly impossible to install. I wouldn't recommend it for a home server unless you have a lot of time on your hands.

Comment: You should state that Gitorious is free whereas Github firewall is not.

Comment: @Simon, for some definition of free, judging from @djs' comment :)

Comment: Gitorious really _is_ near impossible to install. >_< Since I am using Ruby for development, I am going to use instaweb for now until I decide to roll my own web interface using Sinatra (Ruby web application library)